# How to deal with death in disease-free survival analysis?

Tags: regression, survival, epidemiology

If I have disease free survival data (defined as whether or not a particular disease has been diagnosed or not along with the time to that event or loss to follow up) and also overall survival data, how do I deal with deaths that occur without the disease event? Are these censored or should I exclude such patients from the disease-free survival (dfs) analysis? I plan to run dfs analyses for several particular types of disease separately.

Comment: You can do both. I've even seen both types reported in the same paper. "all cause mortality" is one DV and "disease" is another DV. For the latter, deaths from other causes are censored.

Comment: Censoring is perfectly ok, even though they're not "really" censored (you know that they won't develop the disease, as they're dead). Another approach is competing risks analysis, where you consider death as a competing event. If you're interested I can give you some references.

Comment: @PeterFlom do you mean that deaths from the disease in question but undiagnosed in the patient before death should be included, or censored?

Comment: @andrea I'd love some references but I'd prefer it even more if you gave a summary of them in an answer :) Perhaps a competiring risks analysis is uitable.

Comment: It depends on the goals of the analysis.

Comment: @jetistat001 Let's start with the references, I'll try to come up with an answer later :) Fine and Gray's paper: http://bit.ly/Pm6HEM - other useful papers: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22253319 http://clincancerres.aacrjournals.org/content/18/8/2301.abstract http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/170/2/244.full.pdf http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17031868 http://www.ejbi.org/img/ejbi/2011/1/Furstova_en.pdf

Comment: if most of the patients having censoring than death. what is the suitable method will be correct. is it standard survival analysis or cure model?? because i found that many authors say that bias will introduce in heavy censoring. yes, agree with peter dont remove censoring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My interpretation of disease free survival is that the only event is diagnose of return of the disease.  Any other event be it patient withdrawal from the study, lost to follow-up for any other reason or death is a censored event because at that time the defined "event" had not occurred and there is no way for it to either occur or for the investigator to ever find out if it occurred.

You should not remove patients that died.  That creates potential bias.  With survival the whole idea of censoring is to use the incomplete observations and not create bias that could occur if you threw out the incomplete observation.

In comparing treatments I find in agreement with Peter's remarks I have seen it done (and have done myself) analyses of time to recurrence (where death by other causes are censored) and all cause mortality.  Death by disease specific cause is another way such data can be analyzed.

Comment: So, if I'm looking at disease A, then I should censor all deaths including deaths from disease A that were undiagnosed but are listed as the cause of death (this shouldn't happen but obviously it can happen if the disease goes undetected)? The only *events* I should include are **diagnosis** of the disease. Is that right?

Comment: If death is from a recurrence of the disease that went undetected that seems to me to be a different story.  If couldn't happen without the disease reoccurring.  Then I think you should count the death as a recurrence of the disease.  Of course the subject could not have been disease free until death,  The recurrence must have happened earlier.  But diagnosis of recurrence happens some unknown time after the actual recurrence anyway.